# json jsp jqgrid data not populating

Tags: json, jsp, jqgrid

I have gone through all related posts to load my jqGrid from jsp using json call. But am not able to succeed. Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong ?
JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:'dhypo/featurelist.jsp',
    datatype: 'json',
    autowidth: true,
    colNames:['ColOne','ColTwo'],
    colModel:[{name:'id',index:'id'},
                {name:'name',index:'name'}
    ],
    datastr: mygrdata,   
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,7,10],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: false,
        caption:"JSPJSON",
        jsonReader:{
        repeatitems: true,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id",
            root: "rows",
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    }
});
```

JSP CODE is

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json;" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    JSONObject responsedata =   new JSONObject();
    JSONArray cellarray =   new JSONArray();
    try{
        responsedata.put("total",10);
            responsedata.put("page",1);
            responsedata.put("records",50);

            net.sf.json.JSONObject cellobj=new net.sf.json.JSONObject();

            String valaray[] = {"One","Two","Three"};
            net.sf.json.JSONArray cell=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();
            int cnt = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<valaray.length; i++){
               cellobj.put("id",cnt);
               cell.add(cnt);
               cell.add(valaray[i]);
               cellobj.put("cell",cell);
               cell.clear();
               cellarray.add(cellobj);
               cnt++;
            }//for
            responsedata.put("rows",cellarray);
            out.println(responsedata);
            System.out.println("JSON DATA.."+responsedata);
    }catch(Exception exp){
        System.out.println("Exception FROM ........"+exp);
        responsedata.put("rows",cellarray);
        out.println(responsedata);
    }
%>
```

JSON DATA printed from jsp is.....
{"total":10,"page":1,"records":50,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":[1,"One"]},{"id":2,"cell":[2,"Two"]},{"id":3,"cell":[3,"Three"]}]}

My jqgrid is not pupulating with the data. Table structure/pager is displaying.
 - I have tried to change type to 'jsonstring' and use the jason data generated, it is working, so i thinkg the json data is a valid one.

Can anyone please help me to figure out what is wrong here?